# Ubuntu 18.04 lags and hangs even with powerful hardware

Tags: gnome, 18.04, performance, ubuntu-mate

I've got Core i5 3.30GHz / 10GB RAM / AMD Radeon RX 460 graphics card hardware that lags like mad, but it only lags with Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the vendor drivers from AMD, but it didn't help.

Ubuntu 18.04 lags all the time on this machine. It happens when I start typing, when I open a new window, or when I install an application. Is it something related to the CPU? And no, this is not a GNOME memory leak, since I have 10GB RAM free and 2GB swap.

I've been using Debian, OpenSUSE and Ubuntu 18.04 MATE for a whole year, but whenever I try to test Ubuntu 18.04 it gets stuck and it lags.

Comment: Reviewers: How is this question unclear? On Ubuntu MATE, Debian and openSUSE it works like a charm, however it lags like mad on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @Synaxis hi, could you please add a screenshot of your System Monitor with Processes tab with CPU^ column sorted up?

Comment: Looking at other related topics. It seems like the "performance issue" is related to CPU intel core i series ? i3/i5/i7?

Comment: I had a similar problem (system stalling but not crashing) when I tried to run 18.04 with two identical NVIdia Graphics Cards, bought in 2012 - working with old proprietary NVidia drivers only (not Nouveau). I've unplugged one GPU card and ran both monitors with one card only. With 16.04 it was no problem to run 1 monitor/card, with 18.04 that was impossible. (but 2 monitors/single card was possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing because 18.04.02 fixes the majority of issues. But 19.04 will bring kernel 5.0 so let's hope for more.

Answer (score 0):

HiDPI is supported by default in Ubuntu MATE 18.04 and later. Every aspect of Ubuntu MATE 18.04, its themes, its applications, its icons and its toolkit assets have been updated to take advantage of HiDPI. The default GNOME desktop environment in Ubuntu 18.04 has still not caught up with MATE desktop environment when it comes to HiDPI support. I suggest that you stick to MATE for now and lesson learned.

Comment: I mean ALL other distros Work fine on my Hardware, BUT only Ubuntu 18.04 From canonical Have this issue!.
I'm sticking with Ubuntu MATE.(with or w/o AMD drivers it's EXCELENT).
**But that's not a real  solution coming from Canonical.**

Comment: The HiDPI support development on Ubuntu MATE was done by Canonical developers. With GNOME Desktop Environment it's a more complicated situation because GNOME DE is maintained by the community at https://www.gnome.org/ so Canonical doesn't have as much control over the GNOME Desktop Environment project.

Comment: It kinda makes senseI will download 16.04 just for testing purposes and i will give a feedback on this particular performance issue